# How do I limit the number of results from context.Query in DynamoDB in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb, limit, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to limit then number of items returned by DynamoDB while querying a table. I need only the first matching result.

The goal is reduce the number of read units consumed and in an effort to keep the code readable I'm using `context.Query` to query a secondary local index and get the first matching result.

This is the current query:

```
context.Query<TableEntry>(matchId, new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = "SecondaryId-index" })
```

This will return all items who's `SecondaryId-index` matches `matchId`, however I only want the FIRST item it matches.

So I tried this:

```
context.Query<TableEntry>(matchId, new DynamoDBOperationConfig { IndexName = "SecondaryId-index" }).First()
```

As I understand `context.Query` (even though it's lazy) will still execute the entire query and read atleast the first page (when enumerating using `.First()`) and the page will contain more than 1 item, hence consuming more read capacity units than required.

I can't find any documentation on how to limit the query to the FIRST matching item only using `context.Query` in .NET.

Is that even possible? If not, what the next best alternative while keeping the code minimal/clean?

Comment: If what I found is correct, there's no way to limit the number of objects returned when using `context.Query` - https://benfoster.io/blog/20200615-querying-a-dynamodb-partition-with-dotnet/

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but I am suspicious of your assumption.  FIRST_VALUE() is a SQL function.  I would expect Microsoft to add that as part of your query and not return the results from your DB into C# space.  I am not saying that I "know" that it does this, only that it is possible and Query is generally pretty smart about such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. The data model mode is very dumb: it provides a convenient interface to perform common operations without needing to write any boilerplate, at the cost of performance and control.

You'll need to use the low-level [DynamoDbClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDynamoDBClient.html). For an application that needs control over its requests, you'll likely want to drop the `DynamoDbContext`, and instead create your own wrapper around the client that exposes whichever request properties you need.

Keep in mind that the `DynamoDbContext` is still useful for its `FromDocument` and `ToDocument` methods, which are a huge help in (de)serializing objects to/from the attribute dictionaries found in the client's request/responses.

Comment: Any chance you could share the best way to run this query using the least amount of code with DynamoDbClient?

Comment: on a related note, do you know if `DynamoDbContext` allows for strong consistent reads?